# Define $Var(X|Y) := E(X^2|Y) - (E(X|Y))^2$ Use Jensen's Inequality to show that Var(X|Y) $\ge$ 0.

Tags: statistics

I am having trouble proving this: Define $Var(X|Y) := E(X^2|Y) - (E(X|Y))^2$ Use Jensen's Inequality to show that Var(X|Y) $\ge$ 0.

I understand that Jensen's Inequality is $\phi \int g(x)f(x)dx \le \int \phi g(x)f(x)dx  $ but I am not sure how to prove this. Thank you very much in advance. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jensen's inequality says that for any convex function $g(x)$, $E(g(X))\geq g(E(X))$. $g(x)=x^2$ is a convex function, so applying that here:

$$E(X^2|Y)\geq (E(X|Y))^2.$$

So $Var(X|Y)=E(X^2|Y)-E(X|Y)^2\geq E(X|Y)^2-E(X|Y)^2=0$, which is what we want to show.